# overloaded member function error while doing compositon c++

Tags: c++, oop

I am getting this error 
**error C2511: 'printlocation' : overloaded member function 'int (void)' not found in 'creature'**

Here is the code:
Location.h

```
#ifndef location_h
#define location_h

class location
{
public:
setpoint(int,int,int);
getpoint(int,int,int);



private:
    int x,y,z;
};
#endif
```

.cpp code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include"location.h"

location::getpoint(int a,int b,int c)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
    z=c;

    cout<<"give point x"<<x<<endl;
    cout<<"give point y"<<y<<endl;
}
```

code for creature class :

```
#ifndef creature_h
#define creature_h

#include"location.h"
#include<string>
//using std::string;
using namespace std;
class creature
{
public:
    creature();
    moveto(location l);
    getname(string n);
    printlocation(string ,location );

private:
    location lo;
    string name;

};
#endif
```

**code for creature.cpp in which there is an error:**

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using namespace std;


#include<string>
#include"creature.h"
#include"location.h"

creature::creature()
{
    lo;
    name;
}
creature::getname(string n)
{
    name=n;
    cout<<"enter name";
    cin>>n;;
}
creature::printlocation()
:name(n),lo(l)
{
    name=n;
    lo=l;
    cout<<lo.setpoint(int,int,int);

}
```

-----still error exists....---

```
#ifndef creature_h
#define creature_h

#include"location.h"
#include<string>
//using std::string;
using namespace std;
class creature
{
public:
    creature();
    void moveto(location l);
    void getname(string );
    void printlocation(string ,location );

private:

    location lo;
    string name;

};
#endif
```

.cpp

```
    #include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using namespace std;


#include<string>
#include"creature.h"
#include"location.h"

/*creature::creature()
{
    lo;
    name;
}*/
void creature::getname(string n)
{
    name=n;
    cout<<"enter name";
    cin>>n;
}
void creature::printlocation()
:name(n),lo(l)
{
    name=n;
    lo=l;
    cout<<l.getpoint(int,int,int);

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using namespace std;

#include"location.h"
#include"creature.h"
#include<string>

main()
{
    string n;
    int x,y,z;
    location l;
    l.getpoint(x,y,z);

    creature c;
    c.getname(n);
    c.printlocation(n,l);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code looks pretty wrong. Especially how you are declaring the member functions (no return type specifications?).

Comment: I am really sorry,,I forgot to upload the error part...

Comment: This looks all wrong the same way.

Comment: then tell me what can i do? please guide me

Comment: _'please guide me'_ **NO!** You already have two answers here that both address the primary problem and one comment of mine that addresses your secondary.

Comment: the error is still there....error C2511: 'printlocation' : overloaded member function 'void (void)' not found in 'creature'

Comment: Then reflect what you have changed in your question with an update (Leave the original code in order not to invalidate the already existing answers!!).

Comment: I have uploaded the new one but still ...

Comment: I have created an additional answer, foreseeing that ;-) ...

Answer (score 2):

Declaration of function has to specify it's return type (and correct namespace for arguments, since I don't see using namespace std):

```
void printlocation( std::string ,location );
```

Add the same for other declarations:

```
void creature();
void moveto(location l);
void getname(string n);
```

Then call `printlocation` this way:

```
std::string s;
location l;
//... give some value to s and l ...
printlocation( s, l);
```

Also change its name to conform to cammel case: `printLocation`, is better.

Comment: And very probable the call is also wrong, since the compiler complains about a `int (void)` signature.

Answer (score 0):

All your member function declarations have no return type. For example

```
class location
{
public:
setpoint(int,int,int);
getpoint(int,int,int);
//...
```

Ot

```
class creature
{
public:
    //...
    moveto(location l);
    getname(string n);
    printlocation(string ,location );
    //...
```

You have to specify return types of the functions.

For example

```
void setpoint(int,int,int);
```

Also function getpoint logically more corresponds to function setpoint because it sets values of data members of an object

```
location::getpoint(int a,int b,int c)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
    z=c;

    cout<<"give point x"<<x<<endl;
    cout<<"give point y"<<y<<endl;
}
```

So I would rename the function as setpoint. For example

```
void location::setpoint(int a,int b,int c)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
    z=c;

    cout<<"give point x"<<x<<endl;
    cout<<"give point y"<<y<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have fixed the declaration errors mentioned in the already existing answers, give **all of your definitions** in the `.cpp` files the same signature as used in the declaration:

```
// NOTE the parameter defintions!!
void creature::printlocation(string n,location l) { 
    name=n;
    lo=l;
    cout<<lo.setpoint(1,2,3);
}
```

Please also note that the member initializer syntax is only valid for usage in constructor functions:

```
void creature::printlocation() : name(n),lo(l)
                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is wrong!!!
```

**UPDATE:**
You probably meant to provide a parametrized constructor function for `creature`

```
class creature {
public:
    creature() (string n,location l) : name(n),lo(l) {}
    // ...
};
```

Comment: void creature::printlocation()
:name(n),lo(l)..................This is Member Initializer Syntax(when doing composition ,you have to initialize by this way)..correct me if I am wrong...and thnx 4 correcting me...

Comment: @usman_zufi _'correct me if I am wrong ...'_ You are wrong! It's as I said, member initialization syntax is only valid for constructor definitions!